# How yum updating grub

Tags: linux, yum, grub2

When i run:

> yum update

Its update Linux kernel bringing the newest available one, and after rebooting, I find the new kernel listed in grub boot menu, technically which tool written it? is it part of kernel update package which yum ran? what if i downloaded a newer kernel not from yum, can i add it manually to grub menu ?

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: GNU Linux Centos 7

Comment: Use the EDIT button to add this and other relevant information to the body of the question, not as comments down here. This will make your question more clear and complete, and help those who might have answers for you.